# How to get servlet code when the jsp file is processed in the JSP engine

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am using Weblogic for deploying my Java EE applications. I am using JSP technology for my project. I know that the jsp files are processed in the jsp engine and in the life cycle of jsp, it is converted into the servlet code.

Can you please tell me that how I can get the generated servlet code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will vary based on the weblogic set up on your box. If weblogic is compiling your JSPs (you are not pre-compiling them) then it may be under `domains\<YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>\servers\<APP_SERVER_NAME>\tmp\_WL_user\<APPLICATION_WAR>` .

It is generally a good idea to pre-compile your JSPs for performance reasons and add the servlet mappings in the web.xml. You can see a reference to how to do that in weblogic [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jsp/reference.html) under the section "Precompiling JSPs".

Comment: I created a simple jsp page with expression tag <%= "some text" %> then compile this jsp file using java weblogic.jspc . index.jsp. After compilation it created a jsp_servlet directory and _index.class file in this directory. Can you please tell me that how can i map this .class file in the web.xml. and i also want to get the java file created when jsp file loads in the memory before compilation basically i want to see the generated servlet code when jsp is processed in the jsp engine.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I am using Maven and the JSP servlet compiles are sent to the war file in the \target folder of the maven project, i.e. \target\.war\WEB-INF\classes\jsp_servlet.  If you find the jsp_servlet folder you will find the compiled Java servlet code and the class file. With Eclipse you could use the debugger and set breakpoints. A word of caution, the servlet code is complex. If you are trying to debug JSP I would use other techniques, such as temporarily embed EL commands in the JSP to display data and functionality. Also, JSP should have little or no business logic so it would also be advisable to focus on the model and controller.